# ActionbarSherlock overflow menu issue

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I'm developing an android app with Action Bar Sherlock library, and also used Drawer in my app.  I have issue in my overflow menu where the text of menu-items are show space on left side, but I want text on left corner.

I used simple code for it but I can't understand how I solve it.

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/ac_search"
    android:actionViewClass="com.actionbarsherlock.widget.SearchView"
    android:icon="@drawable/ac_search"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="@string/ac_search"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/ac_refresh"
    android:icon="@drawable/ac_refresh"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="@string/ac_refresh"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/ac_more"
    android:icon="@drawable/ac_action_overflow"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="@string/ac_more">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/ac_settings"
            android:title="@string/ac_settings"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/ac_aboutus"
            android:title="@string/ac_aboutus"/>
    </menu>
</item>
```

How to remove space of left side?